# How to enter a date in a cell and have the date for one week later automatically fill another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, date

I want to be able to type in a date in one cell, and then automatically have the date that is seven days from the date I typed appear in another cell in that same row under a different column. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula.

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",A2:A + 7))
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[new date from entered date](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1kPBQZszjerYrHnUWM7-e_k_nShvXPhS70bUisMTrgXQ/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: I like your answer, but isn't the OP just talking about "one cell", so the range/`ARRAYFORMULA` would seem to be unnecessary?